# How do I use the FileUpload Class in an MVC web app

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I am using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447015/uploading-an-excel-sheet-and-importing-the-data-into-sql-server-database) as a reference for what I want to do. I am trying to add a button on my web app that allows the user to click a button upload an excel document straight to a database. In the example I am referencing they use the FileUpload class but It appears I do not know how to use this in a web app.

I attempted putting it in a service file:

```
 FileUpload fileUpload1 = new FileUpload();
```

but I cannot reference the fileUpload1 variable in that context. My best guess at this point is that this is a web app and I am trying to use a windows form class. I get a reference to System.Web.UI.WebControls; when I use it though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if you are trying to upload a specific type of file, this post is not really related to excel, is it?

Comment: check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471179/uploading-files-with-mvc-3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554848/uploading-files-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Are you saying that "FileUpload" is a windows forms class?

Comment: @Patrick no I guess its not directly related I thought I should be as explicit as possible

Comment: @Patrick In the way I am trying to use it, it is not available for use.

Comment: @Chad I am going to check out those links and see what I can work with thanks.