# Processing binary data in Web API from a POST or PUT REST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, binary

I'm currently developing a **REST** web service using **Web API**. I have encountered a problem processing **binary data** (an image) that has been transmitted via a POST request.

From the perspective of the client, I have managed to send binary data using the **jQuery Form Plugin**. But because I'm very new to .NET (I'm a PHP developer), I'm having difficulty processing this binary data via Web API on the server.

To confirm that the jQuery Form Plugin is sending the image data correctly, I have written a working **PHP** handler that makes use of the simple `$_FILE` global variable.

Now I am trying to accomplish the same via Web API. Here is an outline of what I have tried. How do I access the binary data that has been sent?

**Model:**

```
namespace EDHDelivery.Models
{
    public class Oferta
    {
        public int OfertaID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Imagen { get; set; }
        public int ComercioID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller (partial code shown):**

```
public Oferta Add(Oferta item)
{
    /*here my item will have the POST body with form values, 
    automatically serialized by the framework and I think an image binary*/
    var n = item.Nombre; //...etc.
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/967101/955881

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, you have to send the data as `multipart/form-data` (which, I'm pretty sure, you are already doing through the plugin you mentioned) and then you have to extract that data using one of Web API `MultipartContent` providers.

There are plenty of resources explaining how to that:

- [File Upload and Multipart MIME](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)
- [ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-File-Upload-a8c0fb0d)
- [A guide to asynchronous file uploads in ASP.NET Web API RTM](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/)

Answer (score 4):

The same thing I have achieved

This is my upload user Class

```
public class UploadUserFile
{
    string _Token;
    string _UserId;
    string _IPAddress;
    string _DeviceInfo;
    string _FileName;
    string _ContentType;
    Stream _PhotoStream;

   public string Token
    {
        get
        {
            return _Token;

        }

        set
        {
            _Token = value;
        }
    }
    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserId;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserId = value;
        }
    }
    public string IPAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _IPAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            _IPAddress = value;
        }
    }
    public string DeviceInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _DeviceInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            _DeviceInfo = value;
        }

    }
    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FileName;
        }
        set
        {
            _FileName = value;
        }
    }
    public string ContentType
    {
        get
        {
            return _ContentType;

        }
        set
        {
            _ContentType = value;
        }

    }

    public Stream PhotoStream
    {
        get
        {
            return _PhotoStream;
        }
        set
        {
            PhotoStream = value;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my API Controller class

```
 public class UploadUserPhotoController : ApiController
{


    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">
    /// HttpRequestMessage, on the other hand, is new in .NET 4.5. 
    /// It is part of System.Net. 
    /// It can be used both by clients and services to create, send and receive requests and 
    /// responses over HTTP. 
    /// It replaces HttpWebRequest, which is obsolete in .NET 4.5 
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>return the response of the Page <returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var UploadUserFileObj = new UploadUserFile
        {
            Token = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "Token").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
            UserId = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "UserId").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
            IPAddress = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "IPAddress").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
            ContentType = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "ContentType").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
            DeviceInfo = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "DeviceInfo").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
            FileName = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "FileName").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString()
        };
        Stream requestStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;

        if (requestStream!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(UploadUserFileObj.FileName))
                {
                    UploadUserFileObj.FileName = "DefaultName.jpg";
                }

                // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
                using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/locker/" + UploadUserFileObj.FileName), (int)requestStream.Length))
                {
                    // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
                    byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[requestStream.Length];
                    requestStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
                    // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
                    fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                    result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, UploadUserFileObj.FileName);
                }
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                return result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,"Http Exception Come"+ ex.Message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, "Http Exception Come" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, "Not eble to upload the File ");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this code I am using the

> HttpRequestMessage for Transferred data between clinet to server server to client.